# iOS - Swift 3 - UIImagePicker avoid "Retake/Use Photo" for multiple photos

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode8

I know there are similar questions available on SO.

The reason why I'm starting a new topic.

I want to take multiple photos and save them into an array for later usage (when user finished taking photos)

I already read the API about `showsCameraControl, takePicture() and cameraOverlayView`

I managed already to capture multiple photos but I have always to confirm every photo with the "Retake/Use Photo" screen. When tipping on Use Photo, the App saves it into the array.

The same way is already working in the Workflow App from DeskConnect. They have a workflow "Take Photo" where you can choose how many photos you want to take. And they are (in my eyes) using Apple's default controls

Any help is appreciated.

Doesn't matter if it's a solution to avoid "Retake/Use Photo" or to create a custom overly view. For me it is important to keep Apple's default controls so the user feels comfortable with the well known controls.

(I also already took a look on the tutorials Apple provides).

My code so far

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    openCamera()
}

func openCamera() {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageArray.append(pickedImage)
        print(imageArray.count)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    openCamera()
}
```